# How can I access the url a document is loaded from in chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension that redirects the tab to an html file if a url on a blacklist is loaded. This html file includes both continue and back buttons. The only problem is I am using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest and I am unable to find a way to store the url that the request originates from. According to the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest) there is a FrameAncestor property that allows you to access this url, but this is not supported by chrome. Are there any equivalent functions or work arounds?

Comment: Chrome extensions have their own [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). There's no direct analog of frameAncestors in Chrome. There's `initiator` property but it probably won't help you if the initiator is an iframe. More solutions/workarounds are possible depending on what exactly your listener is doing and whether the decision should be made synchronously or asynchronously.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have not been able to find anything in the documentation. My listener checks if the url that prompted the webRequest is in the blacklist. If it is it blocks the request.

Comment: Try using `initiator`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! Can't believe I missed that in the docs. Guess thats what I get for working all night